# Read in CSV, get Column datatypes from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a CSV file into a Pandas Dataframe. I have a string column and a float column. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import decimal
D = decimal.Decimal

pd.read_csv(sourceFileName,
            usecols=["stringCol", "floatCol"],
            converters={"stringCol" : str,
                        "floatCol"  : lambda x: D(0) if x is "" else D(x)})
```

What I would like to do is store the column name and type in a dictionary and then refer to the elements of this dictionary in the read_csv statement.

Something like this:

```
colFormats = {"stringCol" : "str",
              "floatCol"  : "ModifiedDecimalFunction"}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you are doing in your example?

Comment: using `decimal.Decimal` will result in `object` dtype and thus loosing all the magic and power of vectorized ufunctions... Why do you want to use `decimal.Decimal` instead of numpy dtypes?

Comment: this is a column of dollar amounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another dictionary, describing what each type means:

```
formatConverters = {'str': str, 'floatCol': lambda x: D(0) if x is "" else D(x)}
```

Now use

```
pd.read_csv(
    ....,
    converters={c: formatConverters[v] for (c, v) in colFormats.items()})
```